In a vscode extension, how can I create a clickable hyperlink in a text file
I have a vscode extension that can display a log file. In this log file, there are text patterns (not URI's) that I would like to show up as hyperlinks. When one of the hyperlinks is clicked on, I need to be able to perform some operation in typescript.
I've searched quite a bit and found some examples of how to use decorators to apply CSS styles to certain text but I have not seen a way to add the clickable functionality to them.
Is there anything available to do this? Thanks in advance!

Look at registerDocumentLinkProvider().

That appears to be exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!
